# memory game java

Tags: java, memory, colors

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [memory game graphics java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10310661/memory-game-graphics-java)

I'm coding a program that is a 4x4 memory game. Within these 16 boxes will be a pair of integers from 0-7. I have all of that already randomized and coded correctly. Now I'm trying to figure out how to pair the colors with the corresponding integers each time the mouse clicks over the box.

Here most of the code. I know the logic for this game isn't started yet, but I'm more focused on the displayHit method and setColor method right now. Just posting the whole code because maybe I messed up somewhere else.

```
/*Sets the background of your memory board to black*/
public void init() 
{
    setSize(400,400);
    setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    buildBoard(4);

}   
/*This is main in java applets
    You may need to add (not change) a couple things in this method
 */
public void paint(Graphics canvas)
{
    if(firstRun) //for the first run we need to build our random board
    {

        print2DArray(board);
        buildBoard(4);
        firstRun = false;
    } 
    else // once our board is built we will display the game
    {
        displayGame(canvas);
        if (mouseClicked) // if the mouse has been clicked
        {
            displayHit(canvas);//find which box the user clicked
            mouseClicked = false;
        }
    }
}

/*
    DO NOT change this method
    determines if the mouse has been pressed
    sets x and y Mouse to the location of the mouse arrow
    redraws the image
 */
public boolean mouseDown(Event e, int x, int y ) 
{
    mouseClicked = true; 
    xMouse = x;
    yMouse = y;
    repaint();
    return true;
}

/*DO NOT change this method
    redraws the scene
 */

public void update ( Graphics g ) 
{
    paint(g);
}

/*
    pre: none
    post: build an array that holds the memory values for a board of size x size
    the board will hold two of each int from 0 to size randomly placed in the array
 */


public void buildBoard(int s)

{
    int a = 4;
    for (int row = 0; row < a; row++)
        for (int column = 0; column < a; column++)
        {

            board[row][column] = count++ % 8;
        }
    for(int row = 0; row < 4; row++)

        for(int column = 0; column < 4; column ++) 
        {
            int x = (int)Math.floor(Math.random()*4);
            int y = (int)Math.floor(Math.random()*4);
            temp = board[row][column];
            board[row][column] = board[x][y];
            board[x][y] = temp;


        }
}
public static void print2DArray(int[][] arr)
{
    for (int row = 0; row < arr.length; row++)
    {
        for (int col = 0; col < arr[row].length; col++)
        {
            System.out.print(arr[row][col] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}





public void displayGame(Graphics canvas)
{
    canvas.setColor(Color.WHITE);

    for(int i =0; i < 400; i+= WIDTH)
        for(int j = 0; j < 400; j+= WIDTH)
            canvas.drawRect(i, j, WIDTH, WIDTH);
}

/*
    Pre: xMouse and yMouse have been initialized
    Post: A circle is displayed in the correct box on the screen
    Currently the circle is displayed at the mouse location
 */
public void displayHit(Graphics g)
{

    setColor(g);
    centerHit(xMouse, xMouse);
    g.fillOval(xMouse, yMouse, 40, 40);
}

public void setColor(Graphics g)
{

    switch(temp)
    {
    case 0: g.setColor(Color.RED);
    break;
    case 1: g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
    break;
    case 2: g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    break;
    case 3: g.setColor(Color.ORANGE);
    break;
    case 4: g.setColor(Color.CYAN);
    break;
    case 5: g.setColor(Color.MAGENTA);
    break;
    case 6: g.setColor(Color.PINK);
    break;
    case 7: g.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
    break;
    }

}
public void centerHit(int centerX, int centerY)
{
    {
        if ((xMouse > 0) && (xMouse <=100))
            xMouse = 33;
        else if ((xMouse > 100) && (xMouse <=200))
            xMouse = 133;
        else if ((xMouse > 200) && (xMouse <=300))
            xMouse = 233;
        else if ((xMouse > 300) && (xMouse <=400))
            xMouse = 333;
    }
    {
        if ((yMouse > 0) && (yMouse <=100))
            yMouse = 33;
        else if ((yMouse > 100) && (yMouse <=200))
            yMouse = 133;
        else if ((yMouse > 200) && (yMouse <=300))
            yMouse = 233;
        else if ((yMouse > 300) && (yMouse <=400))
            yMouse = 333;
    }



}
```

}

Comment: so what is wrong with it, is an error your getting or is it the colours are just not appearing?

Comment: it only uses the first color in arrayindex of (o,o) whatever switch statement is assigned to that random integer and uses that same color for every click

Comment: You should always use braces around for loops. It makes the code more readable.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like temp is never changed once buildBoard is called. Which is why you always see the same colour.

Comment: I'm kind of confused as to what you are saying

Comment: @user1215307 The temp field is used to determine the colour in the SetColor method but this value is set in buildBoard() then never changed no matter what is clicked on.

Comment: I thought temp is the assigned variable to each of the 16 board blocks and range from pair values of 0-7

Comment: @user1215307 The temp variable has it's value set 16 times but it will always contain the value that it was last given in the buildBoard loop.

Comment: ok that makes a lot more sense.

my next step was writing this then

board[(int)xMouse/100][(int)yMouse/100] = colorIndex;
and switch(colorIndex) now instead but it still just uses one color.

but in my mind that is telling me to store whatever arrayindex is found at those coordinates and store it as colorIndex and switch it appropriately to the color

Comment: @user1215307 The second answer seems closer to what you want. Find out which square you want to use and then set colorIndex = board[row][column];

Comment: I switched the statements to look like this


int x = (int)(xMouse/100);
  int y = (int)(yMouse/100);
  colorIndex = board[row][column];
  board[row][column] = board[x][y];
  board[x][y] = colorIndex;


but the colors don't seem to correspond correctly and when I double click on a the same tile the colors change

Answer (score 0):

this code is fine

```
public void setColor(Graphics g)
```

{

```
switch(temp)
{
case 0: g.setColor(Color.RED);
break;
case 1: g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
break;
case 2: g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
break;
case 3: g.setColor(Color.ORANGE);
break;
case 4: g.setColor(Color.CYAN);
break;
case 5: g.setColor(Color.MAGENTA);
break;
case 6: g.setColor(Color.PINK);
break;
case 7: g.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
break;
}

}
```

but you are not setting temp anywhere in the code to choose which case/colour you want to use. you need to change temp when you click on a square either by hardcoding it or randomly generating a number between 0-7 to set the colour randomly

Comment: board[(int)xMouse/100][(int)yMouse/100] = colorIndex;
  
  switch(colorIndex)

this was my next thought but it is also just selecting one color, but I'm not sure why because I'd imagine that it would look up the value at each array based on the mouse click and assign it it's respecting color